# Launchctl in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to configure MongoDB in OS X Mountain Lion. I've installed with Homebrew; I have followed lots of tutorials, but I have got an issue which I haven't been able to solved.

The issue is related with `launchctl unload` and `launchctl load` commands. My `homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist` is located at `/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.4.6/` and it contains the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>homebrew.mxcl.mongodb</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.4.6/mongod</string>
    <string>run</string>
    <string>--config</string>
    <string>/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.4.6/mongod.conf</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
  <key>KeepAlive</key>
  <false/>
  <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
  <string>/usr/local</string>
  <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
  <string>/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.4.6/data/log/mongod.log</string>
  <key>StandardOutPath</key>
  <string>/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.4.6/data/log/mongod.log</string>
  <key>HardResourceLimits</key>
  <dict>
    <key>NumberOfFiles</key>
    <integer>1024</integer>
  </dict>
  <key>SoftResourceLimits</key>
  <dict>
    <key>NumberOfFiles</key>
    <integer>1024</integer>
  </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

If I executed `sudo launchctl load -w /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.4.6/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist`, in `http://localhost:28017/` appears MongoDB's `http diagnostic access` information. But if I execute `sudo launchctl unload -w /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.4.6/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist` does not disconnected and appears the same in the `http://localhost:28017/` url.

To shutdown Mongo I've need the following commands:

```
use admin
db.shutdownServer()
```

How can I do to shutdown Mongo automatically with `launchctl unload` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this, first I installed MongoDB 2.4.6 with brew, and then used launchctl to load and unload.  In my testing, it sends a SIGTERM to the mongod process which then shuts down as expected.  Here are the commands I used as well as the logs for the `mongod` process:

Commands:

```
launchctl load -w /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.4.6/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist
launchctl unload -w /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.4.6/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist
```

Logs:

```
tail -f /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
Tue Oct 22 17:33:32.774 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=13192 port=27017 dbpath=/usr/local/var/mongodb 64-bit host=adamc-mbp.local
Tue Oct 22 17:33:32.774 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.6
Tue Oct 22 17:33:32.774 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
Tue Oct 22 17:33:32.774 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin minimountain.local 12.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.4.0: Wed May  1 17:57:12 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2050.24.15~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Tue Oct 22 17:33:32.774 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
Tue Oct 22 17:33:32.774 [initandlisten] options: { bind_ip: "127.0.0.1", command: [ "run" ], config: "/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf", dbpath: "/usr/local/var/mongodb", logappend: "true", logpath: "/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log" }
Tue Oct 22 17:33:32.775 [initandlisten] journal dir=/usr/local/var/mongodb/journal
Tue Oct 22 17:33:32.775 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Tue Oct 22 17:33:32.806 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017
Tue Oct 22 17:33:32.806 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
Tue Oct 22 17:34:21.682 [signalProcessingThread] got signal 15 (Terminated: 15), will terminate after current cmd ends
Tue Oct 22 17:34:21.682 [signalProcessingThread] now exiting
Tue Oct 22 17:34:21.682 dbexit: 
Tue Oct 22 17:34:21.682 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Tue Oct 22 17:34:21.682 [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 9
Tue Oct 22 17:34:21.682 [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 10
Tue Oct 22 17:34:21.682 [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 11
Tue Oct 22 17:34:21.682 [signalProcessingThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
Tue Oct 22 17:34:21.682 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Tue Oct 22 17:34:21.682 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Tue Oct 22 17:34:21.682 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Tue Oct 22 17:34:21.682 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Tue Oct 22 17:34:21.683 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: final commit...
Tue Oct 22 17:34:21.692 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: closing all files...
Tue Oct 22 17:34:21.692 [signalProcessingThread] closeAllFiles() finished
Tue Oct 22 17:34:21.692 [signalProcessingThread] journalCleanup...
Tue Oct 22 17:34:21.692 [signalProcessingThread] removeJournalFiles
Tue Oct 22 17:34:21.692 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Tue Oct 22 17:34:21.693 dbexit: really exiting now
```

I did this several times to confirm the behavior.  In Chrome at least the status page no longer responds and I receive an error (as expected) once it has been shut down.

The only difference between what I am doing and what you have posted is that I am not using `sudo` (in fact it refuses to load or unload due to dubious ownership of the file).  So, I changed the ownership of the plist file to root and tried `sudo` with the same results.

The only way I was able to recreate a failure to unload was as follows:

1. Start with `sudo launchctl` (root is the owner of the plist file)
2. Change ownership of the plist file back to my regular user
3. Try to unload without `sudo`

This fails with an error however:

```
launchctl: Error unloading: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb
```

Note: Subsequently changing the ownership back to the regular user made the unload successful

Similarly, this also produces the same error:

1. Start without `sudo` (regular user owns the plist file)
2. Change ownership of the plist file to root
3. Try to unload with sudo

I was unable to recreate the silent failure you seem to be having with any of the various combinations I tried.

Some information gathering tips which may give you a clue:

- When you launch with launchctl, what does the output of this command say: `launchctl list | grep mongodb`? (it should list something like `13340  -   homebrew.mxcl.mongodb`
- If you run this same command after you run unload (without error), it should show the exit status in that middle column (-15)
- Sometimes it can take a while for MongoDB to exit - so tail the log (see example above), see if the TERM signal is being received
- Why is it you are using sudo?  Have you installed brew as root?  If so this might be at the core of the issue here - generally it is not recommended to run MongoDB as root.